# Difference between Phillips 00 and 000

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I'm not really at home in the screwdriver world, and since this question relates to my purchase of a MBP I figured I could ask the question here. Whats the difference between a Phillips 00 and a 000 screwdriver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

000 is smaller and has thinner blades. 
00 is larger and has thicker blades.

Using a tool that doesn't exactly match the screw means you can't get proper surface contact. This increases the chance of stripping the head of the screw on removal - especially if the screw threads have locking adhesive.  For assembly, the wrong tool makes it harder to torque the screw properly.

[With a high quality tool](http://www.wihatools.com/200seri/261serie.htm) and a screw that isn't too tight, you can sometimes mix 000/00 for screw and tool, but it's not ideal as the difference is significant for the tolerances in a MacBook Pro. If you're looking for an entire kit, [this driver set](http://www.ifixit.com/Tools/Home-Tech-Toolkit/IF145-047) is quite nice as well. You do get "a little play" any time there is a socket/bit connection; but for home use, iFixit sells great value and good quality tools.

Answer (score 0):

A difference in sizing, I don't think it's particularly a large difference.

There is a difference though, if you're looking after your screws then the correct driver is always best.

Comment: And is there a difference between 00 and #00?

Comment: One's got a hash and the other doesn't. Nah, there's no difference, just a difference in how they get listed, the 00 is a standard reference code.